# Is Radio interface Layer (RIL.dll) available for windows 8 desktop application?

Tags: windows-8

I am using a Windows 8 laptop and trying to pinvoke RIL.dll but I do not find it anywhere in my Windows directory. Is this dll available for Windows 8 desktop applications and Surface Pro also?
Thanks.

Comment: I never heard about this DLL. Where did you get it and what do you want to use?

Comment: It is Radio Interface Layer provided by microsoft to get cell tower information from which we can inturn get location. Problem is I am not able to find it in my windows 8 laptop.

Comment: this DLL seams to be only usable on old Windows mobile devices, so it is no longer part of newer Windows or Phone versions.